# How to get a specific item

Tags: jquery

How can I get the value `item.title` using jQuery?

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for item in items %}
      <div class="carousel-item active"">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{item.image.url}}">
        <a href="{% url 'item_detail' item_pk=item.pk %}">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block carousel-challenge" >
            <h5>{{item.title}}</h5>                    
          </div>
        </a>              
      </div>
    {%endfor%}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want all of them, just `$('h5').text()` will work. If you want a specific one we'd need to know what event you're trying to run the code under. It would also help to see your effort to solve this yourself so we can help you debug it.

Comment: It is not element, its a value of an element.

Comment: it is the `innerText` of an element. the `h5` tags that you create in a loop are anonymous. give them a unique Id (as for example from a database primary key) otherwise you could only retrieve them all and select by index. to answer the jQuery question, we need to know in which context the lookup is triggered.

Comment: Need to be closed as `too broad` or with any other reason like `unclear` or `off-topic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use text() or html() to fetch.

```
$('.carousel-caption').find('h5').text();

$('#carouselExampleIndicators').find('h5').text();

$('#carouselExampleIndicators').closest('h5').text();

$('h5').text();
```

There are so many ways to fetch the result.

Comment: If it solves the problem, so this question should be a duplicate question. Why need an answer here?

Answer (score 0):

you can give unique id and access using `onload` or `ready` or anyother method

```
<h5 id="text">{{item.title}}</h5>

$(document).ready(function(){
var data= $('#text').html();
    alert(data);
});
```